# how to achieve one to many relationship in ampscript

Tags: ampscript, marketing-cloud

I have built my ampscript code for one to many relationship but every time i am only getting first row for my lookup data extension as i have one customer id in my first data extension and based on this id i have 3 products records related to this customers id, So i try to populate all 3 records from lookup data extension i am getting only first row repeated record. Please review my below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Wish List Items</h2>

<table>

  <tr>
<th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Product Quantity</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
%%[

var @ids,@count,@prodctid,@acount
set @ids = AttributeValue("Id")
set @acount = RowCount(LookupRows('WishList__c','Id',@ids))
set @count = RowCount(LookupRows('Wish_List_Item__c','Wish_List__c',@ids))

FOR @i = 1 to @acount DO ]%%

%%[FOR @j = 1 to @count DO

   set @prodctid = Lookup("Wish_List_Item__c","Id","Wish_List__c",@ids)


]%%

<td>%%=Lookup("Wish_List_Item__c","Name","Id",@prodctid)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=Lookup("Wish_List_Item__c","Product_Code__c","Id",@prodctid)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=Lookup("Wish_List_Item__c","Product_Quantity__c","Id",@prodctid)=%%</td>
  </tr>

%%[next @j  

]%%

%%[
next @i ]%%


</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to used [Field](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/field/) and [Row](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/row/#Row) AmpScript function to get the each matching records.

```
%%[
SET @ID = AttributeValue("Id")
SET @Count = LookupRows('Wish_List_Item__c','Wish_List__c',@ID)

IF RowCount(@Count) > 0 Then
    For @i = 1 to RowCount(@Count) DO
]%%
    <tr>
        <td>%%=Field(Row(@Count,@i),"Name")=%%</td>
        <td>%%=Field(Row(@Count,@i),"Product_Code__c")=%%</td>
        <td>%%=Field(Row(@Count,@i),"Product_Quantity__c")=%%</td>
    </tr>   
%%[
    Next @i
EndIf   
]%%
```

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve Campaign attributes using AttributeValue method?

Comment: You mean Profile/Preference Attribute ?

Comment: Well, I'm new to AMPscript, not sure about Profile/Preference. I want to get Campaign Code and then use that in email body. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where is your Campaign Code store? in DataExtension? AttributeValue is a AmpScript function and it only use for check if field is present in DataExtension or not.

Comment: Campaign Code is on the Campaign record that we create in Marketing Cloud.